# Dynamic str_replace vars (without knowing the name)

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a DB with pages with some variabiles in the content, for exmpale [var1], [name], [foo],..

Example of page:

> hi [name],
>
> are you [var1] or [foo]?

All these variables should be replaced with the corrisponding php variabiles on output

[var1] become $var1
[name] become $name

I know that i can use str_replace manually to change this variabiles, for example:

```
echo( str_replace( array( [var1], [name], [foo] ), array( $var1, $name, $foo), $page ));
```

But there is a way to create a loop that automatically replaces all these vars?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider an array containing some string as follows:

```
array("var1","name","foo")
```

So here is the solution:

```
<?php
$rowdata=array("var1","name","foo");

foreach($rowdata as $key=>$value){
$rowdata[$key]="$".$value;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($rowdata);
echo '</pre>';
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It is working. First of all find all such strings which are in bracket. and then use the preg_replace to replace the content.

```
$text = '[This] is a [test] string, [try] it.';
preg_match_all("^\[(.*?)\]^", $text, $matches);
$data = array_combine($matches[1],$matches[1]);

foreach($data as $key =>$value)
{
$text = preg_replace('/\['.$key.'\]/', '$'.$value, $text);

}
echo $text;
```